# MTG Does "Emerging" cause summoning sickness?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I emerge a card like Mockery of Nature, does it get summoning sickness?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your Mockery of Nature will have summoning sickness when it enters the battlefield.

When you pay the emerge cost of [Mockery of Nature](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMockery%20of%20Nature%5d), it is just an alternate casting cost.  As such, it doesn't change the summoning sickness rule in anyway.

Comment: This answer is a bit loose with terminology. It is an alternate casting cost. For the sake of the new player, lets use proper terms

Comment: @NeilMeyer please feel free to edit it to improve the terminology.  It's not clear to me how it could be better, else I'd have written it that way!